# How to flash Raspberrypi over the Network

Tags: pi-4

I have a need in which I need to flash my Raspberry Pi sdCard connected to Rpi4 without removing it from Rpi4 over the network.

I'm using Raspberry Pi Desktop Image, after making some change to existing image I need to flash the same image to remote location over the network.

please assist me with this.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: you mean the standard raspberry pi OS image with your changes? Can't be done.

Comment: there is Raspberrypi Desktop image in my sd Card, and I've same image im my server, but after some changed like installing some packages and removing unwanted ones. now I need to flash this image to my Pi4 over the network (without removing the sdCard).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too broad in nature.

Comment: `flash this image to my Pi4 over the network` - can't be done